# How to declare a persistent variable when using left recursion in bison/flex?

Tags: c++, recursion, bison

Here is the part I'm talking about:

```
block       : statement 
            {
                NBlock* myBlock = new NBlock();
                myBlock->AddStatement($1);
            }
            | block statement 
            {
                std::cout << "More than one statement" << std::endl; 
                myBlock->AddStatement($2);
            }
;
```

Here is an excerpt from the instructions for this assignment:

> The majority of grammar actions will only require setting $$ to a new instance of the node, as
>   with NRotate. But there are a couple of special cases to watch out for.
>
> The main_loop action simply needs to grab the block it has and set the global g_MainBlock
>   pointer to it. This global block should then also have SetMainBlock called on it.
>
> The other special case is the actions for block. When the first statement is matched, you want to
>   construct a new NBlock, and add the statement to this new NBlock’s list of statements. But when
>   subsequent statements are matched, rather than creating a new NBlock, you should simply add
>   the new statement to the already existing NBlock.

How do I achieve this?

ETA:

```
/* Add one union member for each Node* type */
%union {
    Node* node;
    NBlock* block;
    NStatement* statement;
    NNumeric* numeric;
    NBoolean* boolean;
    std::string* string;
    int token;
}

%error-verbose

/* Terminal symbols */
%token <string> TINTEGER
%token <token> TLBRACE TRBRACE TSEMI TLPAREN TRPAREN
%token <token> TMAIN TROTATE TFORWARD TISHUMAN TATTACK TISPASSABLE TISRANDOM TISZOMBIE TRANGED
%token <token> TIF TELSE

/* Statements */
%type <block> main_loop block
%type <statement> statement rotate forward is_human is_passable is_random is_zombie ranged

/* Expressions */
%type <numeric> numeric
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply find the original object in `$1`, and move it into `$$`, instead of creating a new one.

The first statement sets `$$` to `myBlock`. The recursive statement grabs it from `$1`, and sets `$$` to it.

P.S. You should use smart pointers, i.e. `std::shared_ptr`, in order to avoid leaking memory due to parsing failures.

Comment: When you say "find the original object in $1", I am not sure what you mean. I understand that 41 will be the first block, which would have myBlock declared in it, but how do I access it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "41".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Probably a typo. The OP meant "$1".

Comment: Ok. You need to show all your %type, or %union declarations in your question, which define how you're mapping all the elements to datatypes. Generally, in the first block you would set `$$=myBlock`, or `$$.something=myBlock`. Then, in the second statement you would use "$1" or "$1.something" to access it. See http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_6.html#SEC44

Comment: @SamVarshavick Thanks, I added the part you requested. I looked through the docs before posting but couldn't figure out how to apply the stuff there to my problem. My brain might be fried. Also, yes I usually use smart pointers but we get the framework as part of the assignment.

Comment: So, it looks to me like in the first statement, you just need to set "$$.block=myBlock;" at the end. That'll shove the myBlock into that grammar element. In the recursive statement, you'll look in "$1.block", i.e. "NBlock* myBlock = $1.block", and after the add(), once again "$$.block=myBlock;".  $$, $n, et al, refer to your %union declaration that corresponds to the specified rule element, $n, or the result of the rule element, $$.

Comment: Couple tweaks- instead of $$.block = myBlock it's just $$ = myBlock, and the same for the other .block statements but it is working so I am eternally grateful, I've been stuck here for far too long!

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I simply forgot the fine points of yacc/bison's voodoo. It's been quite a while, since my compiler design days...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would write this as

```
block       : statement 
            {
                $$ = new NBlock();
                $$->AddStatement($1);
            }
            | block statement 
            {
                std::cout << "More than one statement" << std::endl; 
                ($$ = $1)->AddStatement($2);
            }
;
```

This uses the sematic value of `block` to pass the created `NBlock` object between productions.